Can I re-register a 2FATOTP TOTP authenticator?
Is it possible to re-register a 2FATOTP authenticator with an account after that authenticator has been deleted from the account?
Or is that not possible because the secret key is only given once to a particular authenticator?

https://superuser.com/questions/1860083/identifying-2fa-authenticators-in-an-account#comment2951121_1860083

This question should include more details and clarify the problem. If this is about a 2FA linked to a website. Contact the support team for that website. We are NOT that support team and we cannot help you remove a 2FA associated with your account. Submitting multiple identical questions is a guaranteed way of becoming question banned.

It depends on the website or service, of course (practically each site implements TOTP flows on its own), so there cannot be a truly general answer – but so far I've never seen a single site that would let you provide your own TOTP key; it seems to always be that the site generates a key and the user imports it into the authenticator (or into multiple authenticators), not the other way around.
